# display content of the folder as dir but only for specific folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a generic site in /var/www/ and I did put my webpages in html, including sub folder that I am planning to use to store pdf and doc files.

Now; I would like that when a user go to mysite/files/docs or mysite/files/pdf, they can see the list of files, but even if they click on the parent link on that page, or if they type the url (like mysite/files); they won't see the list.

Is possible to enable the file display feature but only for certain folders? I did check Apache manual and it has options to set in httpd.conf file, although it was not really showing how to turn on or off specific folders; just how to turn it on and off globally.

I have .htaccess files that I use for settings, but even in that case; I can't find a way to display only some folder content and not others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file in each directory `files/docs` and `files/pdf`

Then inside each .htaccess file add

```
Options +Indexes
```

That's it. It will display the files of only those 2 directories.

Comment: Brilliant; it is so simple that I wonder why this was not on the top of the Apache documentation. Thanks!